# Three.js OrbitControls captures all key events

Tags: events, three.js, key, controls

I've been implementing all the NeHe demos in three.js (just to amuse myself).  I also use the OrbitControls.  Unfortunately, I discovered that OrbitControls appears to capture all keydown events, so unless I place an absolute div over some section of the page, click on that div, THEN press a key, I never get the key events.
OrbitControls is listening to the renderer element, mine is listening to the document. Perhaps I am missing something?
Otherwise, this seems unfortunate.  I can think of a couple of other ways around this (don't use they keyboard, a special div that covers the screen and re-emits key events I don't want, etc.).  None of these seems very satisfactory.
Suggestions?

Comment: Strange. Save for touch events, OrbitControls should be using window for its events and allowing for propagation, something along the lines of "window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );"  at 903 in the release repository: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js Maybe something in the demo code has modified this. Check to make sure it's window and check  for preventDefault and stopPropagtion calls in your orbitControls.js class before resorting to something hacky - I think something is simply not right with the event propagation.

Comment: Hm.  You could be on to something, but...  In fact, there was a stopPropagation call in my eventHandler, BUT as long as OrbitControls is in the loop MY event handler is never called so I can't see how it is a factor. I just tested that, but I may be missing something.  The code I am using is [here]:  (https://github.com/rkwright/nehe-3js-epub/blob/develop/EPUB/lesson16/lesson16webgl.xhtml)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just now but it was solved when I put the `onKeyDown` on the same `div` as the `OrbitControls` is using as its DOM node.